# RESTful webservices implementation on Embedded Linux(c/c++)

Tags: xml, rest

I am working on Embedded Linux (running on BeagleBone) and I want RESTful web services to run on my board.

My objective is to send/receive data (in XML format) to webserver.

I dont have support for Java on my ARM board, so which source package I can use to implement RESTful?

I was trying staff but it doesnt seems to be working. Any help on RESTful is welcome.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to implement this solution? I have exactly the same scenario.